# Trying to send AJAX data to WordPress hook

Tags: ajax, hooks

I'm trying to send jQuery data via AJAX to a WordPress template file.   I've tried several different techniques and solutions based on other questions posted that pertain to this topic,  with no success.  I can successfully pass data from the functions.php file to my promotions.php template file.

However, I cannot get the data from my JavaScript file (ajax-javascript.js) file to the functions.php file.  When the page loads, my $_POST variable is empty and my console.log message from my ajax-javascript.js file reads **'Server response from the AJAX URL 0'**.  To me, a response code of '0' means there is something wrong with my wp_ajax hooks but I cannot figure out what.  Is there something wrong with the hooks or is it something else that I'm over-looking?

Here is my latest attempt:

**ajax-javascript.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var numberOfPromos = 4;
  var data = {
    numberOfPromos: numberOfPromos
  };

  $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function(response) {
    console.log('Server response from the AJAX URL ' + response);
  });
});
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ajax_javascript_file' );

function add_ajax_javascript_file() {
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_for_frontend', 'ajax_for_frontend', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_custom_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-javascript.js', array('jquery') );
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_number_of_promos', 'get_number_of_promos' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_number_of_promos', 'get_number_of_promos' );

function get_number_of_promos() {
    echo $_POST['numberOfPromos'];  
    die();
}
```

**promotions.php** - where I call my function in my Wordpress template file

```
<div><?php echo $get_number_of_promos(); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but ...

You need to pass your "action" identifier with the data, like so:

```
var data = {
    'action': 'my_action',
    'whatever': 1234
};
```

In your case, that action would be `get_number_of_promos`.

The example is from the Codex page about AJAX, which you should read carefully: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass absolute URLs in WordPress. Use `ajax_for_frontend.ajaxurl` in place of absolute URL.

Try using this (untested) -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var numberOfPromos = 4;

    jQuery.ajax({

        url: ajax_for_frontend.ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'get_number_of_promos',
        },
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log('Server response from the AJAX URL ' + response);
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the way you are calling your function is incorrect :

```
 <div><?php echo $get_number_of_promos(); ?></div>
```

You are calling a function (get_number_of_promos) as a string ($).

It should be :

```
 <div><?php echo get_number_of_promos(); ?></div>
```